# luks impact cryptsetup benchmark

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, performance, encryption, luks

i have a laptop with i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 4, SSD and 8gb ram and am considering FDE. how do i know if the results i got from running cryptsetup benchmark are good or not?

```
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b  1009,1 MiB/s  2940,9 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    85,5 MiB/s   635,5 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   189,4 MiB/s   331,6 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   759,4 MiB/s  2321,9 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    85,4 MiB/s   636,4 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   188,6 MiB/s   347,8 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  1842,9 MiB/s  1837,9 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b   614,2 MiB/s   626,0 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   341,6 MiB/s   342,8 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  1706,6 MiB/s  1695,2 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b   616,7 MiB/s   627,6 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b   340,1 MiB/s   341,2 MiB/s
```

Answer (score 2):

With the default `aes-xts-plain64` cipher, you're usually good even on entry level / mobile systems, as long as the CPU supports AES-NI. That should make the encryption fast enough to be unnoticable, even for SSD storage.

To put things in perspective how much of a difference AES-NI makes, here is a random benchmark run on the same machine:

```
for bits in 256 256 256 512 512 512
do
    cryptsetup benchmark -c aes-xts-plain64 -s $bits
done
```

With AES-NI enabled (`modprobe aesni_intel`):

```
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-xts   256b  1373.2 MiB/s  1425.4 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  1501.9 MiB/s  1482.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  1461.8 MiB/s  1424.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  1145.6 MiB/s  1164.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  1239.6 MiB/s  1203.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  1064.8 MiB/s  1224.6 MiB/s
```

With AES-NI disabled (`rmmod aesni_intel`) it's a lot slower:

```
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-xts   256b   145.6 MiB/s   174.6 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b   170.4 MiB/s   151.6 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b   127.0 MiB/s   168.5 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   128.9 MiB/s   124.0 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   124.2 MiB/s   119.9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   124.8 MiB/s   123.0 MiB/s
```

Even without AES-NI, for regular desktop use you might not notice too much of a difference (most things get cached in RAM after all), and either you need encryption (and then performance doesn't really matter) or you don't, so not too much point worrying about it.

To really know for sure, only one way to find out - set it up then test some things you normally do. The best benchmark is the one you run yourself.